# Deleting elements of list without specifying position in list

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I have a list {a,b,c,d,e} and I'd like to delete the letters "c" and "e" to get a list of {a,b,d}.

I would like to specify "c" and "e" as my input to a function and not the position of the letters, so I cannot use the Delete function. Is there a way to go about doing so?

Comment: See `DeleteCases`.

Comment: Or use `Delete` in combination with `Position`, or use `Select` etc. There are many options.